# Need specifications of antenna to use for Increasing 3G/4G strength of a 4G router

Tags: routers, tv-antenna

I live in India, Bangalore. I have an Airtel Huawei B310s-927 4G router. Since the network coverage in my area is very bad, I want to improve the 4G signal strength by using an antenna. But what antenna should I use? I tried searching elsewhere and found I can use an "SMA male" antenna, but what specifications Mhz? Can I buy a [900MHz SMA Male](https://www.amazon.in/900MHz-Connector-Magnetic-Mount-Antenna/dp/B007POE82U/) antenna?

Following is the instruction page of the router next to the router next to a USB drive for size.

[image: Router backside]

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off-topic. Just make sure that you're asking about specifications and all is well.

Comment: This is what a google search of "India 4G Frequency" gave. Currently in INDIA, 4G LTE band-40 having 2300 to 2400 MHz (TD-LTE) frequency range is active (online) and offered by the operators in indian territory.